# STAN slowed by rank deficiency?

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, stan

Does having a set of predictors which are not linearly separable slow down the model fit in STAN? If so, why?

I have tried to test this, and it appears to slow down the fit. I fit a model with 10,000 rows and 61 linearly separable columns except for the intercept, 100 iterations for two chains and it finished in 7 minutes.

I fit a model with 61 columns which had columns which were linear combinations and it has taken over 18 minutes to finish the first chain.

Comment: Can you post code for a reproducible example?

Comment: I can try to come up with an example, but I cannot share the data that I am working with so will take a few.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does. I think you are introducing multicollinearity and your model is not identified. Stan is not very happy with non-identifiability. I know that you can solve not-perfect multicollinearity with tight normal or cauchy priors but I think you will need hard priors for perfect multicollinearity. If one of your predictors is a linear combination of the other 60. You can exclude that one which is basically a hard prior of 0 on the coefficient for that predictor.

Comment: Keep in mind that the adding priors will make the model identifiable in a technical sense, but in the presence of perfect multicolinearity one must wonder what, precisely, your priors have accomplished since the data contributes precisely nothing. The stan manual has a great example for a model with two intercepts.

Comment: You are absolutely right. My comments about the priors should be read as:  there is a connection between adding soft constraints with imperfect multicollinearity and excluding a variable because it does not contain any new information with perfect multicollinearity. It is not meant as advice to use hard constraints as a default prior when you know you have multicollinearity.